# How to passing a data type into a parameter instead of a variable

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing, type-conversion

I wrote a simple input validation function to check if the user has entered the right data type and if not it'll keep asking them to re-enter until they do. Now this is something that I use a lot and in most cases I am using it on multiple data types at a time. So instead of duplicating the function and changing the data type of num inside the method is there a way I can simply just pass a data type as the parameter and have it change inside the function too?

```
float cinInputValidation(){
    float num;
    while(!(cin>> num)){
        cout<< "Error: Invalid Input.\n"
        << "Please try again: ";
        cin.clear();    //  Clears cin flags if user enters variable of the wrong data type.
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');  //  Ignores up to 100 characters or until a new line.
    }
    return num;
}
```

Now I am aware of typeof() and I have a hunch I can use it as a parameter like so

```
cinInputValidation(typeof(float))
```

but what would I do about the functions datatype itself and the type declaration of the num variable? Or is this just not possible.

Comment: With a template most likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705907/how-to-passing-a-data-type-into-a-parameter-instead-of-a-variable#comment38314570_24705907) correct pointed out, you can change `cinInputValidation()` into a function template so the type can be specified via a template parameter at the call site:

```c++
template<typename T>
T cinInputValidation() {
    T num;
    while (!(cin >> num)) {
        ...
    }
    return num;
}
```

Later on...

```c++
float f = cinInputValidation<float>();
double d = cinInputValidation<double>();
```

Comment: Ahh that works! I went and looked up templates and I had everything right minus when I called the function in the actual program, I was leaving out the '<float>' thanks!